# How to prevent changes being overwritten when merging branches?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, branching-and-merging

I'm new to Git (coming from Subversion and Bazaar).

When I've been working on a branch and made a commit, and since then the master has had some commits take place, when I merge my branch into the master, I find some strange occurrences:

- In my commit and the master's commits, we've both created a new file with the same path. It decides to completely override the master's file with my file, without warning of conflict!
- A pre-existing file that has been modified in both branches presents me with a conflict warning, and inline comments are added for *some* parts, but for other parts it actually overwrites without warning.

Can I tell Git to be stricter with these conflicts? I don't want it to overwrite files without warning, and if it's going to comment files for me to inspect, I'd prefer it provide absolute comments of total differences.

If not, I'm forced to determine the files that have been modified by both myself, and then manually merge them.

Comment: This seems more appropriate for http://superuser.com as it is only a side aspect of programming, and not a programming question _per se_.

Comment: @Phrogz: You may be right. I think Stack Exchange should have clearer guidelines. Every time I visit Super User or Stack Overflow I check the about page as I'm not sure *exactly* what it's for.

Comment: Per the FAQ, "software tools commonly used by programmers" are certainly on topic here.

Comment: I disagree with your comment, @Phrogz.  As of the time of this comment, there are 15,127 questions tagged for git.  It's not like the question was how to do a Powerpoint animation.

Answer (score 2):

When I try your first scenario, I get the following output:

```
Auto-merging conflicted
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in <filename>
```

Your second scenario will produce conflicts on lines that are different between the two versions, but not lines that only changed in one version or the other.  This is expected behavior.

Git actually handles these sorts of conflicts better than most any other VCS.  There's something else about your process that's causing issues.  Maybe you have some rare config setting.  Maybe you're misinterpreting the meaning of a flag you're using on one of the commands.  Maybe some files haven't actually been committed in your or your colleague's working directory.  Maybe you're in a different branch than you thought.  Find an exact, reproducible sequence of commands that doesn't do as you expect, and we can try to help you from there.

Comment: Thanks, just putting a test case together now!